# Void pointer as function parameter

Tags: pointers, c++-cli, void

I use two structures emulate "OR" & "AND" logic gates. These structures are the  same. I need to create a function which get as parameter one of these two structures. Something like :

```
int myfunc(void *mystruct, unsigned char param)
{
switch (param)
{
case 'o': ... break; //"OR" logic gate struct
case 'a': ... break; //"AND" logic gate struct
}
}
```

How to realize this idea in managed code c++/cli?

Comment: Please add more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use a union for your two different structs and then pass the union:

```
struct AND_gate {
    // ...
};

struct OR_gate {
    // ...
};

union gate {
    AND_gate and_gate;
    OR_gate or_gate;
};

int myfunc(gate * my_gate, unsigned char param)
{
    // ...
}
```

Alternatively, and perhaps better (hard to tell with the limited information available), it sounds like your design might benefit from using inheritance:

```
struct gate {    // parent class
    // ...
};

struct AND_gate: public gate {
    // ...
};

struct OR_gate: public gate {
    // ...
};

int myfunc(gate * my_gate, unsigned char param)
{
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might mean how do you return a structure ... in which case just like this:

```
typedef struct
{
...
} YourStruct;

YourStruct *Function(...)
{
    return &GlobalStructureForAndGate;
}
```